# NetBSD - Can we force semget() to return same semid?

Tags: unix, semaphore, netbsd

I am working on a NetBSD system.

As I recollect from my memory from a book on UNIX programming by Richard Stevens, I lerant that semget() call returns different values for different invocations, even for the same thread.

I recently happen to see a group of processes where different invocations of this semget() to be returning same set of values for respective IPC keys. I see that same process image in different boxes also yield same value for semid.

So, my question is - Is there anyway we can force semget() to exhibit this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

semget always returns the semaphore associated with the specified key. If you specify the same key, you will get the same semaphore. I believe this has to be true even with netbsd.

```
int semget(key_t key, int nsems, int semflg);
```

Comment: I think my question was NOT clear enough - I mean that for same IPC key different calls for semget return different semid (due to slot sequencing). This is true even for same thread. NOw my question is - is it possible to retain the same semid as well ?